# Shared preferences isn't created

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using the shared preferences and on bootup of the application I am checking for some values:

```
public static String getFirsUsageAppFromSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString("firstUsage", null);
}
```

This is the first method that I am calling it. When I am installing from Android studio the application on a real phone, the shared preferences file is created in /data/data/my.package.name. But when I am building an apk and installing that apk with:

adb install com.my.package.name

the shared preferences file isn't created and my application crushes. Anyone knows why the shared preferences aren't created when i am installing it via adb?
I am building the application in android studio: Build -> Build APK(s).

Comment: Share your error log and `SharedPreferences` editing line.

Comment: Edit your question pls.

Comment: The first time when I am using the SharedPreferences is:
    String firstUsageApp = 
    SharedPreferencesHelper.getFirsUsageAppFromSharedPreferences(
                getApplicationContext());

and the method getFirstUsageAppFromSharedPreferences is above. From what I know is that this file is created when I try to get some value or to store some value. The error is lower in the logic and not related to the shared preferences but to a value that is not retreived.

Comment: Show the code where you are putting some values into `SharedPreferences`

Comment: assuming you don't set any weird flags, installing via adb is identical to installing via AS

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may have this issue, there is a difference if you install the application via android studio and if you use adb install. Via android studio is the same as if you have installed the application and clicked on the icon, so the MainActivity is started. In my case I was installing the application but wasn't clicking on the icon, but another application was calling a service. In that case the code in MainActivity won't be executed until you open your application.